# Optimisation test services allude to 'inline script block #5', what does this mean

Tags: performance, page-speed, optimization, load-time

Optimisation text services like Gmetrix and Pingdom Tools often provide feedback like 'inline script block #5', what exactly does this mean and how do you go about identifying and solving this problem.

Comment: This means that there is a script blocking your page being redered. That's all that can be sait for now. Please provide a bit more details. Maybe Gmetrixs tells you about which script causes the blocking and what it is used for. Gmetrix does tell you at least "The following external CSS files were included after an external JavaScript file in http://www.yourdomain.com/. To ensure CSS files are
downloaded in parallel, always include external CSS before external JavaScript."

Answer (score 2):

As noted in Seb's comment immediately under the question, this indicates there is a script or asset request blocking your page being rendered.

More than likely, it is a javascript or css call for a plugin or add-on tracking service. Many such services often recommend/instruct website owners to insert their scripts/css calls as close to the top of the  section as possible.  Depending on the plugin or script, you may be able to optimize page load by moving them to the end of the source code, following the closing  tag and before .

Examples of such scripts/services could be:

- ShareThis or AddThis
- Salesforce or Hubspot injected forms
- Campaign/Marketing tracking services such as DoubleClick, Floodlight, CrazyEgg
- 3rd-Party Plugins and Embeds